# innerhtml and value failed using html() and val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML='';
document.getElementById('files').value='';
```

I replace pure js with jquery below, and supirising it doesn't perform the same thing.

```
$("#file").html("");
$("#list").val("");
```

Comment: any error in your browser console? did you include jQuery in your page

Comment: So, what's the difference?`

Comment: For starters your selector in js is files and in jquery it's file

Comment: Just checking the question is correct ... in the first section, you're setting list `innerHTML`, but in the second set, it's setting using `val()`. Also, first section expects `files` whilst second expects `file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#list").html("");
$("#files").val("");
```

you have confused the names